1970's short story with the last garden on top of a skyscraper on a world covered in concrete
I'm looking for a sci fi short story I read in the 1970's about a world covered in concrete and cities with a last garden with bees etc hidden away at the top of a skyscraper.
The story was in a paperback anthology that may have also contained the story The Names of God.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you read this in an anthology or a magazine?  Do you remember any other stories you read together with this one?

Hi, it was a paperback anthology. It may also have had the story the names of god?

If you have a few details slightly off, that may be Asimov's 2340 A.D.  It involves a man named Cranwitz whose family has kept the samples of the last of Earth's former life forms (other than humans.)
Quoting from my very old, beaten up copy of Buy Jupiter:

“This year we've reached the goal. The birth rate now exactly matches the death rate; the population level is now exactly steady; construction is now confined to replacement entirely; and the sea farms are in a steady state. Only you stand between all mankind and perfection..."
“Because of a few mice?”
“Because of a few mice. And other creatures. Guinea pigs. Rabbits. Some kinds of birds and lizards. I haven't taken a census--”
“But they're the only ones left in all the world. What harm do they do?”
“What good?” demanded Bunting.
Cranwitz shook his head stubbornly. “They take up so little room; consume so little energy. If all were wiped out, you might have room for what? For twenty-five more human beings? Twenty-five in fifteen trillion?”
Bunting said, “Twenty-five human beings represent another seventy-five pounds of human brain. With what measure can you evaluate seventy-five pounds of human brain?”
“I know,” said Alvarez, “but the difference between perfection and not-quite-perfection is that between life and not-quite-life. We are so close now. All Earth is prepared to celebrate this year of 2430 AD. This is the year when the computer tells us that the planet is full at last; the goal is achieved; all the striving of evolution crowned. Shall we fall short by twenty-five--even out of fifteen trillion. It is such a tiny, tiny flaw, but it is a flaw."

In the end

 he acquiesces, and euthanizes them all, and himself

It's one of several stories he wrote on the theme, from different directions.  Contrast it with the story that follows it, in that collection - 'The Greatest Asset' which involves setting up artificial ecology tests inside of asteroids. (They were both in response to the quote at the beginning of the first story; he was asked to write a story about it, and at first wrote one supporting it, then the second one, refuting it.)

Can be read online free  https://novel12.com/buy-jupiter-and-other-stories/2430-ad-993142.htm

That's the same story I thought of from the OP description.

@Ángel - Yep, and 'It may also have had the story the names of god?' -- well, the "9 Billion Names of God" is close enough to Asimov's style (even if Clarke wrote it) that I'd be amazed if they haven't been anthologized together at least a few times.

What's the quote Asimov's responding to?

@Malady - "Between midnight and dawn, when sleep will not come and all the old wounds begin to ache, I often have a nightmare vision of a future world in which there are billions of people, all numbered and registered, with not a gleam of genius anywhere, not an original mind, a rich personality, on the whole packed globe."

J.B. Priestly.


Ty, I'll find these stories, I read it a very long time ago.

A second possibility could be The king of the hill by Chad Oliver.
Here you can find a (slightly critical) review: it talks about an overcrowded society where the animals are illegal and the main character, one of the richest men in the world, still owns a kind of reserve where the last animals are living.
In the end

 while the humanity is doomed to extinction, he succeeds to save the animals sending them to a safe habitat on another planet (Titan), where it is implied that raccoons will evolve to be the next dominant species.

I read it on the anthology Catastrophes! (where there is also a story called "No other Gods", in case the story "The names of God" is a misremember of the title), but it is featured also in other anthologies, such as Again, Dangerous Visions

Ty I'll take a look
